# Как запустить работу скрипта на сайте с django?

Tags: python, django

как запустить работу скрипта на сайте с django? есть скрипт, который собирает мета-теги с поисковой выдачи мне надо реализовать его запуск на сайте, через кнопку и нужен ввод данных от пользователя (запрос и кол-во страниц)

как это можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если сложности с запуском в фоне, то посмотрите на `apscheduler` и `celery`

Comment: Я так понимаю, автору нужно реализовать запуск сбора метатегов, их сохранение и просмотр на сайте с поиском и пагинацией

Comment: @DmitryKozlov мне нужно реализовать сам запуск этого скрипта,
он уже есть,
надо подвязать его к запуска с сайта, не могу понять, как это сделать